# Table of content highlight topic on scroll

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on Reactjs and have implemented a table of content in the right sidebar. TOC is working perfectly on user click but I also want to add when the user scrolls the page then the current h2 or h3 should highlight in the right sidebar (TOC) how can i do this

here is my code

```
   const handleClickOnTopic = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  // Remove highlight from previous clicked target
  const previousActive = document.querySelector('.activeee')
  if (previousActive) {
    previousActive.classList.remove('activeee')
  }

  const target = e.currentTarget
  target.classList.add('activeee') // Add highlight to the currently clicked target

  const nav = document.querySelector('.header')
  const height = nav.getBoundingClientRect().height - 50

  const id = target.id
  const heading = document.getElementById(id)
  const splitted = heading.href.split('/')
  const lastElement2 = splitted.pop()
  const topicId = document.querySelector(lastElement2)
  window.scrollTo(0, topicId.offsetTop - height)
}

export function TableOfContents() {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  const headings = useTocHighlight(ref)
  if (!headings.length) return null
  return (
    <TocContainer ref={ref}>
      <h4>On this page</h4>
      <ul>
        {headings.map((heading, i) =>
          heading.url ? (
            <li key={i} data-depth={heading.depth}>
              <a
                id={`heading${i}`}
                onClick={(e) => handleClickOnTopic(e)}
                href={heading.url}
              >
                {heading.text}
              </a>
            </li>
          ) : null,
        )}
      </ul>
    </TocContainer>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state to highlight the link in the table of content. You can lift up the state to the parent element where "Table of content" and "article" is the children.

Then see which heading is present in the viewport using javascript. And change the state according to the heading. You can play around with different values of dimensions of elements to check what is the right time to update the state.

This article may help you:
https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll